# Ограничение доступа к папке на сервере используя БД

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как ограничить доступ к папки используя базу данных... С помощью `.htaccess`
Весь интернет перерыл не нашел.

Comment: Какой-то странный у вас интернет.

Comment: Наводящий вопрос:  
Сервер Ваш, и Вы можете сами на нем запускать любой процесс (как в ответе @eicto), если да, то следуйте ответу, если нет, то расскажите подробнее, что Вы хотите сделать. В лоб с помощью htaccess это не решить (ну разве что свой модуль для apache написать), но возможно, что для решения Вашей задачи есть другие пути.

Comment: я там шибко не присматривался, но точно есть mod_auth_mysql не скажу насколько он стабилен/актуален... ну и ещё имейте ввиду что в 2.4 auth по другому конфигурируется.

Comment: Сервер впс, личный. Доступ ко всему есть. Сейчас стоит ограничения по isp panel. Ограничение доступа к папки. Хотелось бы управление логином и паролем из бд. Возможно ли это?

Comment: ну а чем вас ответ из интернета не устраивает ?

Comment: @Jamals Engine, Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: Думаю актуальность не ахти:  

> Version 3.0.0 is available. This version fixed a bug in the AES encryption and added a new parameter to specify the user name column in the group table. 2005-6-22

Answer (score 3):

http://www.kraeg.ru/node/8